# I like to discuss my little MVVM framework and present my coding. Is stackoverflow the right place for this?

Tags: discussion

I like to discuss my little MVVM/NHibernate framework and present my coding. Is stackoverflow the right place for this?

Answer (score 8):

Is your code broken in a way that you have exhaustively tried to fix it yourself and can narrow down the issue to the smallest snippet of code that reproduces the issue, and there are no duplicates on the site that already address the problem? Then yes. Are you looking for improvements to your *working* code? Take it to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Do you just want to *talk* about it? Then no, we don't want that.

Comment: With your explanations, Code Review seems to be the better idea for my question. THANKS!